# SwiftUI APN Background Updates affecting UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-push-notifications

I'm writing a text messaging app similar to Apple's built-in messaging app.

The first view like Apple's shows the latest text received or sent from or to each recipient and like Messaging, tapping on that row takes you into the chat view of that recipient.

On each view I declare the following to refresh the data when a background APN notifications is received:

```
let pub = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .AYSTextMessagesUpdate)
```

and then:

```
.onReceive(pub) { (output) in
  self.msgsVM.fetchHeaderTexts()
}
```

to updated the data.  I have the same code in the chat view to update the texts of that particular thread.

The problem is when the user taps on the chat view and then later a notification comes the UI of the parent view is invalidated with kicks the user out of the chat view and back to the main view.

I'm using a NavigationLink embedded in a list in the first view to navigate to the chat view.  When the notification comes in the corresponding data refresh invalidates the parent view causing the UI to of the parent view (which isn't currently the top view) to invalidate and redraw the user is kicked back to the parent view.

I either need to decouple the two views so one's update doesn't invalidate the other or somehow prevent the data refresh on the parent view to be postponed until that view is being displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a very elegant fix but this seems to work:

In the first view I define these two state variables:

```
@State private var needsRefreshed = false
@State private var listDisplayed = true
```

Then after the list I added this:

```
.disabled(self.showNewMessage)
      .onAppear() {
        self.listDisplayed = true
        if self.needsRefreshed {
          self.msgsVM.fetchHeaderTexts()
          self.needsRefreshed = false
        }
      }
    .onDisappear() {
      self.listDisplayed = false
    }
```

then I change the .onReceive code as follows:

```
    .onReceive(pub) { (output) in
  if self.listDisplayed {
  self.msgsVM.fetchHeaderTexts()
  } else {
    self.needsRefreshed = true
  }
}
```

Seems to work.